# Client Side Rendering a Field Type

Tags: 2013, people-picker, client-side-rendering

I am creating a new form with the help of List Field Iterator, it works fine. The problem is that the people `picker column` is rendered in 2010 fashion and not 2013. I am looking for a solution which will client side render all the people picker columns with the default rendering template of 2013, i.e. `SPClientPeoplePickerCSRTemplate`.

To be more precise if anyone can help me with a solution which will custom render a field TYPE as I want to render all the columns of a particular field type without giving names of the column.